# getting error while trying to copy data using google_bigquery_data_transfer_config using terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, terraform

I am trying to setup a bigquery data transfer configuration using terraform. I am using my personal gcp account. I have a setup of terraform on my laptop so that terraform and gcp can work together.

Trying this below code in main.tf,

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "4.18.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "google" {
  # Configuration options
  project="gcp-project-100"
  region="us-central1"
  zone="us-central1-a"
  credentials = "keys.json"
}

data "google_project" "project" {
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "permissions" {
  project = data.google_project.project.project_id
  role   = "roles/iam.serviceAccountShortTermTokenMinter"
  member = "serviceAccount:service-${data.google_project.project.number}@gcp-sa-bigquerydatatransfer.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}

resource "google_bigquery_data_transfer_config" "query_config" {
  depends_on = [google_project_iam_member.permissions]

  display_name           = "my-query"
  location               = "US"
  data_source_id         = "scheduled_query"
  schedule               = "every wednesday 09:30"
  service_account_name   = "service-${data.google_project.project.number}@gcp-sa-bigquerydatatransfer.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  destination_dataset_id = "practice"
  params = {
    destination_table_name_template = "test_gsod"
    write_disposition               = "WRITE_TRUNCATE"
    query                           = "select station_number , year , month,day, mean_temp,mean_dew_point ,mean_visibility from `bigquery-public-data.samples.gsod`"
  }
}
```

---

terraform apply is failing with below details

google_bigquery_data_transfer_config.query_config: Creating...
╷
│ Error: Error creating Config: googleapi: Error 403: The caller does not have permission
│
│   with google_bigquery_data_transfer_config.query_config,
│   on main.tf line 27, in resource "google_bigquery_data_transfer_config" "query_config":
│   27: resource "google_bigquery_data_transfer_config" "query_config" {

Can someone please help me , how to do this setup properly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved now. I have used below piece of code along with bigquery admin role for my terraform service account.

```
    terraform {
      required_providers {
        google = {
          source = "hashicorp/google"
          version = "4.18.0"
        }
      }
    }
    
    provider "google" {
      # Configuration options
      project="gcp-project-100"
      region="us-central1"
      zone="us-central1-a"
      credentials = "keys.json"
    }
    
    resource "google_bigquery_data_transfer_config" "query_config" {
      display_name           = "my-query"
      location               = "US"
      data_source_id         = "scheduled_query"
      schedule               = "every 15 mins"
      destination_dataset_id = "practice"
      params = {
        destination_table_name_template = "test_gsod"
        write_disposition               = "WRITE_TRUNCATE"
        query                           = "select station_number , year , month,day, mean_temp,mean_dew_point ,mean_visibility from `bigquery-public-data.samples.gsod`"
      }
    } 

Now it is working fine. Thanks.
```